# position images in several columns

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, multicol

I'm trying to put to images in two columns on a single beamer slide. This is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{In short}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item How to get from here..
                \begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures/demo0-obs.png}
                \end{figure} 
            \vfill\null
        \columnbreak
            \item ...to here    
                \begin{figure}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figures/demo0.png}
                \end{figure}    
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result
[image]
What am I doing wrong? It seems to me that I have the exact same code for every column. Why are results different? I tried adding different image placement options to the figure environment like t,h p, b but none of that has helped. Could you please offer some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

beamer has own "multicols" environment, so the best is to use it:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{In short}
\begin{columns}[t]% instead of multicols
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item How to get from here \dots
        \begin{figure}\centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figures/demo0-obs.png}
        \end{figure}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item ...to here
       \begin{figure}\centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figures/demo0.png}
       \end{figure}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know about this column environment. Works swimmingly!